# UTF Regex with preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need a regeular expression for german words with ä,ü etc.

When I test this regex on this website https://regex101.com/

```
/^\p{L}+$/u
```

all is fine, but on my server I upload a CSV and want to parse the words.
When I call with the word "Benedikt"

```
preg_match("/^[\p{L}]+$/u", $attributes[0])
```

I get false. The encoding of the CSV is UTF-8, when I convert it to ANSI, all is good but the ä,ü etc. is not shown correctly, so I think I should convert it to UTF-8.
But why is it returning false?

Comment: If it _actually_ returns `false` (not `0`), you could try using [`preg_last_error()`](http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php) to find out what the error is.

Comment: No it is returning 0. Could it be something with the server? Encoding or whatever?

Comment: `var_dump(preg_match("/^[\p{L}]+$/u", "Benedikt"))` writes `int(1)` on my machine. Perhaps you need to share (a subset of) the CSV file with us so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: You can download here: https://www.file-upload.net/download-12727065/udfser_new.csv.html
When I test the same statement as you, it returns 1, too. But the encoding of "Benedikt" is ASCII, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because your csv file starts with a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). If you remove this, the regex works perfectly. I have confirmed it with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
function remove_utf8_bom($text)
{
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}

$csvContents = remove_utf8_bom(file_get_contents('udfser_new.csv'));
$lines = str_getcsv($csvContents, "\n"); //parse the rows

foreach ($lines as &$row) {
    $row = str_getcsv($row, ";");

    $firstName = $row[0];
    $lastName = $row[1];
    echo 'First name: ' . $firstName . ' - Matches regex: ' . (preg_match("/^[\p{L}]+$/u", $firstName) ? 'yes' : 'no') . '<br>';
    echo 'Last name: ' . $lastName . ' - Matches regex: ' . (preg_match("/^[\p{L}]+$/u", $lastName) ? 'yes' : 'no') . '<br>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The regex match the text successfully, and the ü in Glückmann is shown correctly on the page.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

**preg_match()** returns **1** if the pattern matches given subject, **0** if it does not, or **FALSE** if an error occurred.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @AndreasWeichselgartner try dump($attributes[0]); function if the error isn't in variable, if $attributes[0] is defined or as such.

Comment: If this can help http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#94424

Comment: Dump returns string "Benedikt" in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: ASCII and UTF-8 encoding of "Benedikt" are identical, so that's not the reason it is failing. See my answer below for the real reason.